# For a minimal SD to enable USB Host boot, are bootcode.bin and config.txt sufficient?

Tags: pi-3, boot, config.txt

For network booting, the according [Foundation tutorial](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-boot-modes) describes how one modifies the `boot/config.txt` on a "standard" SD installation to program the OTP memory in order to enable USB *Host* boot (by default, only USB *device* boot seems to be enabled).

In order to save the time needed to write a full-fledged O/S on a SD just for installation, I'd like to create a minimal SD that simply sets the necessary OTP bits.

Hence, does `bootcode.bin` interpret `program_usb_boot_mode=1` in `boot/config.txt`?

Or, even better, is `boot/config.txt` on its own already sufficient?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: How long does it take to install Raspbian-lite? How long to make a custom SD?